# Run function if checkbox checked and value in input over 1000

Tags: jquery

Right now, I'm trying to make a script for the gambling website `csgopolygon.com` and want to add the feature that doesn't allow you make bets over 1000 credits. I want it to set back the value in the `betAmount` input to 1000 if the checkbox which enables `AntiGreed` is checked and the user wrote a number over 1000 in the input with the id `betAmount`. This is what I got so far:

```
$("#betAmount").keydown(function () {
if($('#antigreedcheck').is(':checked')){
    if(parseInt($("#betAmount").val()) > 1000) {
        $("#betAmount").val('1000');
    }
}
});

$("body").append('<div class="modal fade" id="settingsscript">'+
            '  <div class="modal-dialog">'+
            '   <div class="modal-content">'+
            '           <div class="modal-header">'+
            '           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>'+
            '           <h4 class="modal-title"><b><center><a href="http://bytec0.de">bytec0de&#039;s</a> csgopolygon script</center></b></h4>'+
            '           <h5 class="modal-title"><center>Win monies easily!</center></h5><br><br><br>'+
            '           <center><input type="checkbox" id="antigreedcheck"></input>'+
            '           <label for="antigreedcheck">AntiGreed</label><br></center>'+
            '           <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></center>'+
            '        </div>'+
            '   </div>'+
            '  </div>'+
            '</div>');

$("div .input-btn").append('<div id="setcolor2"></div><br><b><a href="#" style="font-size: 2em;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#settingsscript"> Settings</a></b></div></div>');
```

This code doesn't seem to work, because every time I tick the checkbox and type in more than 1000 in the betAmount input, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Because tyou have wrong selectors. Use # for id, . for class.

Comment: `$('antigreedcheck')` and `$("betAmount")` are missing the `#`

Comment: It did, but heres still an issue... It replaces the first 4 digits with 1000 after I wrote the fifth digit. Doesnt matter what the first 4 were.

Comment: @AlivetoDie Look at this GIF. https://gyazo.com/644834367b077dc6a3dea55723bc80df

Comment: I want the AntiGreed feature to don't allow the user to bet more then 1000 credits, so, everytime he has the feature enabled in the settings and tries to write a value higher than 1000 in the Input, the value in the input should get set back to 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ***need to convert `keydown` to `keyup`*** and also add missing `#` and `{` and it will work fine.

Check below:-

```
$("#betAmount").keyup(function () {
  if($('#antigreedcheck').is(':checked')){ //# missing
      if(parseInt($("#betAmount").val()) > 1000){ //# missing and { missing too
          $("#betAmount").val(1000);
      }
  }
});
```

***Working example:-***

```js
$("#betAmount").keyup(function () {
  if($('#antigreedcheck').is(':checked')){ //# missing
      if(parseInt($("#betAmount").val()) > 1000){ //# missing and { missing too
          $("#betAmount").val(1000);
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="antigreedcheck"/>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="betAmount"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `#` here `#betAmount`:

```
 $("#betAmount").keyup(function () {
  if($('#antigreedcheck').is(':checked')){ 
      if(parseInt($("#betAmount").val()) > 1000){
          $("#betAmount").val(1000);
      }
  }
```